# Unknown USB Device (Set Address Failed) for Apple SD Card Reader

Tags: windows, macos, usb, drivers, sd-card

**Update**

===========================================================================

I was never able to fix this problem. At some point I reformatted my drive and reinstalled everything (Mac + Windows) and the problem went away. However, when using Windows, I do have to do a cold boot if I want to access the JetDrive. If I load MacOS first and do a restart into Windows, the drive won't be visible. I believe that during a warm boot the drive remains in some kind of locked state.

===========================================================================

I have a MacBook Pro with MacOS Sierra and Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Since recently, I am having problems with accessing my SD Card Reader (Transcend JetDrive Lite). It won't mount in Windows, but I can access the drive in MacOS and it is working fine when Windows is launched using Parallels. The driver is shown as "Unknown USB Device (Set Address Failed) in Device Manager.

Yesterday, I was able to fix this issue by removing the card, uninstalling the driver, plug the SD Card back in and "Scan for hardware changes" in Device Manager. The correct driver (Apple SD Card Reader) installed and I was able to access the drive again. Today however, after a reboot, the same problem occurred and I can't fix it this time.

Some background info:

- The drive is formatted as NTFS
- I've assigned the D: Drive letter to the drive using the Registry (Maybe "Set address failed" has something to do with this?)
- The drive does not show up in Disk Management
- This problem might have occurred for the first time since installing Anniversary Update.
- In the past I have extended my Windows Partition using a tool, and since then I am experiencing minor booting problems. For example, MacOS won't show my Windows Partition in "Target Disk Mode", and it takes up to one minute to show the bootcamp menu when holding down the ALT-key during boot. In the bootcamp menu I can select the Windows Partition.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?